# How to get/config socket from Pyro Proxy

Tags: python, sockets, pyro, pyro4

I want to set socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE of a Pyro4 object for keeping heartbeat. Is there any way to do this? Or workaround is also welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The socket is wrapped by the Pyro.Proxy, so that I don't know how to trigger like: socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 10)

Comment: The defaut setting is 7200s which is too long, the connection would be lost after 2-3 mins.

Comment: Is setting the SO_KEEPALIVE setting not good enough (which you can do via normal Pyro configuration settings)?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can get to the actual `socket` object in the Proxy via `proxy._pyroConnection.sock` but then you're using an internal API, so no guarantees that your code keeps working.